# Connecting to virtual machine on host computer

Tags: svn, freebsd, version-control

I ultimately wish to run a FreeBSD virtual machine on my Vista computer to act as a server so I can test several projects. Im getting the FreeBSD vm set up with apache, php etc but how do I connnect to the vm from my computer? How do I configure/find the ip address I need to connect to?

I am using VMWare.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if you did not choose static ip for the guest machine, it will be obtained via dhcp; if you have only one virtual machine, the ip will be always the same

on the bsd console type

```
ifconfig
route get 0.0.0.0
```

to see the ip address and the default gateway

you can "see" the vm by its ip address you found above

Comment: the IP will always be the same? If it's bridged to the host network, and you turn off the VM for >`DHPC-lease-time`, another device can get that address from the DHCP server

Comment: the most usual setting is NAT - therefore the address will be the same for only one vm; this is the prerequisite I built my answer from - a NAT-ed interface

Answer (score 0):

VMWare is configured by default to bridge the Ethernet of the guest O/S with the host, with a private DHCP server. You can run the configuration utility to change this. When bridging the client O/S to the LAN, it is polite to turn OFF the DHCP server, or an angry SysAdmin will track you down.